# Procedure: [dbo].[insertreading] has an unresolved reference to object [hubdb].[dbo].[addnew]

Tags: sql-server, function, azure, stored-procedures, permissions

I've just set up a new azure SQL database through Visual Studios Community Edition 2013. I've added a bunch of tables and updated them to the cloud without any problems. Now I'm receiving the error above while trying to access either a function locally (from a procedure) or a stored proc remotely via ado.

Executing either from VS works fine. I've tried with and without the database/schema reference. I've simplified the function to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].addtwo
(
    @param1 int,
    @param2 int
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @param1 + @param2
END
```

and the calling stored proc to:

```
select * from hubdb.dbo.addnew(1, 2);
```

I get the error on updating the sp. I've been trying different things for the last few hours. I've checked the security on the schema, it lists nothing and I haven't set anything up so assume default. The spelling/case is correct and the function exists. I've also tried putting the functionality in the sp and calling that via ADO but I get the same error there.

As far as I can see the function call is correct, fully qualified and I have access to it. Or maybe I'm misreading the security.

Update: When trying to run the sp remotely I get 
    *invalid object name 'insertreading'.* 
If I fully qualify it I get 
    *'Reference to database and/or server name in 'hubsrv.dbo.insertreading' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.'*
I have specified the correct server/database in the connectionstring and this error should pertain to cross database queries which this is not.

Stephen

Comment: Well it's called addtwo not addnew, but maybe that's just a typo in your question...

Comment: And that's a scalar function, you should use it like "select function(x,y)" -- if it's a table valued function then you can use it in the from part.

Comment: I knew I was staring at that for too long. Correcting the typo makes the function call from the procedure work. It is a tvf. I've been trying as inline, table and scalar. Remotely the problem still occurs so having weeded out that red herring (thanks) are there permissions I need to set to access an sp from a windows client?